# Yii2 migration add new column to the table

Tags: php, yii2

Using the migration feature in Yii2, I'am trying to add a new column called `'authorization_key'` on the table `'users'`. My `up`-function is as follows:
My initial `run` function was this

```
 public function up()
 {
     $this->createTable( 'users',   [
         'id' => 'pk',
          'username' => 'string UNIQUE',
          'password' => 'string'
     ]); 


  }
```

and when I run `./yii migrate up`
 after `./yii migrate/create`, the table was created .

But after adding `$this->addColumn('user', 'authorization_key'for', 'string UNIQUE');` , i.e.
the new `up` function is

```
public function up()
     {
         $this->createTable( 'users',   [
             'id' => 'pk',
              'username' => 'string UNIQUE',
              'password' => 'string'
         ]); 

         $this->addColumn('user', 'authorization_key'for', 'string UNIQUE');
      }
```

and  I run

```
 ./yii migrate up
```

, it was not working and didnt create new column ,
but it was showing

```
No new migration found. Your system is up-to-date.
```

How can new columns in a table be added using migration or what is the error here? Am I missing some commands here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The migration you created had been marked as done (check table 'migration' in your database). If you want to add new column to the that table you have to down the migration and run it again or create new migration.